# how can i use Numerical Analysis to analyse equation from the fourth degree?

Tags: numerical-methods

i meant that i know way to analyse equation from first , second ,or third degree , Using a table of $(X)$ and $(y)$ .
How can i solve this table with equation from the fourth degree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you use to solve the second degree . if you added on it column with ${ X^2 , X^3 and X^4 }$ it would came as third degree , 
Now use this new formate and add new Colume with ${ x^3 , X^4 , X^5}$ . with respect the unknowns ${A1 , A2 , A3 , A4 }$ and solve them as the same way .